# Wordpress wpadmin : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Tags: wordpress

I am using woocommerce on my wordpress site. I wanted to filter out specific products by category. When I clicked the filter button, this error occurs:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /..../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1841

I checked and executed this : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/fix-wordpress-memory-exhausted-error-increase-php-memory/

by adding  `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );` on wp-config, but still error occurs

Also, I don't have  **iThemes Security** installed on my PC as seen on this link(though I installed before, I just only uninstalled)

[WordPress Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes) in wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1832](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840555/wordpress-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-tried-t)

FYI, I only have more than 10k of total products on my database.

Does anybody know?

Comment: You'll have to do it higher up, try in php.ini http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits

Answer (score 0):

To debug, you need to check how much memory php.ini allows the php to use.

create a phpinfo.php file under your website, put phpinfo() in:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Visit corresponding page and check PHP memory_limit number. If its too small,  you can increase it by editing the php.ini. The path informaion of php.ini is also displayed on http://your.domain/phpinfo.php URL.

Then, find **memory_limit =** line:

```
memory_limit = 1024M ; /* Change the 1024M to your needs */
```

In addition, you may want to try to display less product in a single page. This may save some memory for you.

Comment: Yes if you can, or restart Apache is enough if you can not restart WHM.