# WordPress: Allowed memory exhausted caused by wp-db.php

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a WordPress site and errors occurs anywhere at random times while browsing the site or dashboard. It's always the same byte 53248 or 8192. Very small bytes in fact. But there is something else going on there other than insufficient memory.

I guess there is a bug somewhere. It throws the error from `/wp-includes/wp-db.php` from line 1896:

```
$num_rows = 0;
if ( $this->use_mysqli && $this->result instanceof mysqli_result ) {
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {
            $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
            $num_rows++;
    }
} elseif ( is_resource( $this->result ) ) {
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {
            $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
            $num_rows++;
    }
}
```

Note: Why the downvotes? The problem was really from something else that is hard to catch and not from PHP or server configuration.

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe someone downvoted the question due to the title that is not really precise. Something like "WordPress: Allowed memory exhausted caused by wp-db.php" could be better. I've edited it and I'm awaiting for a peer review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final Answer and Solution:
The problem was coming from badly written and overpriced (the pro version) plugin. **The Ultimate Member:** https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/

There is an option in this plugin's settings. "Cache user". It doesn't matter if it is Yes or No. The plugin creates a row in **wp_options table** for every user you have. For example my site had **17.000 users** and that plugin added **17.000 rows** to **wp_options** table like:

- Cache Adam user - yes
- Cache Smith user - no
- Cache John user - yes
- and on and on and on...

**So that creates 17.000 extra rows in wp_options table. If you had 100.000 users that would 100.000 extra rows.** What an atrocity! Like this plugin is designed to destroy your web server. So that even 6 Cpu core and 12 GB ram wasn't helping. Getting Http 500 errors all the time.

The only way of stopping this is edit the plugin's source code and remove the line that updates wp_options table. And then remove all that data from wp_options table.

Previously:

```
ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' | grep php-fpm

   517.02 Mb php-fpm: pool www
   455.77 Mb php-fpm: pool www
     5.46 Mb php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
     0.35 Mb grep php-fpm
```

Now the site loads 5x faster and without any 500 errors:

```
ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' | grep php-fpm
26.21 Mb php-fpm: pool www
25.29 Mb php-fpm: pool www
24.99 Mb php-fpm: pool www
24.72 Mb php-fpm: pool www
24.28 Mb php-fpm: pool www
23.83 Mb php-fpm: pool www
23.16 Mb php-fpm: pool www
23.06 Mb php-fpm: pool www
22.25 Mb php-fpm: pool www
21.85 Mb php-fpm: pool www
18.76 Mb php-fpm: pool www
5.46 Mb php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
0.35 Mb grep php-fpm
```

Answer (score 2):

Your server is configured to only allow 256 MByte of memory for the PHP process. Wordpress is using more than that. The number of bytes you're trying to allocate (53248 or 8192) does not matter, you're hitting the limit because you are requesting more memory than allowed.

It seems your database is too big and wordpress needs more memory to work on your data. Please re-configure your server (allow more memory to be used), or raise the issue with wordpress developers so that the code is able to run with only 256 MByte.

Comment: It doesn't change if I raise it to 512 MB either.

Comment: It is not that memory is insufficient but there is a bug either from a plugin or from a theme.

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer by Dawid Loranc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858785/5789458)

*"The problem was caused by iThemes Security plugin. I turned off it and errors have gone. I'll investigate this problem more and edit this answer if I'll know what part of this plugin caused exceeding memory limit."*

Comment: I don't have that plugin.